# How do I access file in WEB-INF in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using Tomcat. I would like to put the config file in `WEB-INF` instead of the default root class path which is `WEB-INF/classes`. Currently I put the `config.xml` in `WEB-INF` and use the following relative addressing to locate it:

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread()
    .getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("..//config.xml");
```

Is this the correct way to do?

Or should I use the `getServletContext().getRealPath("config.xml")` first? But I don't know how to obtain the `getServletContext()` in a `.java`. (I tried to `new HttpServlet` for obtaining `getServletContext()`, but since it is an abstract class, can't be instanced... how can I get the `getServletContext()`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `getRealPath()` is not guaranteed to work, e.g. if your webapp is not expanded from a war file there is no 'real path' on the filesystem to a file inside the war file.

Since you say you are using a [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), you can get the ServletContext out of the [ServletContextEvent](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent.html):

```
sce.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **getServletConfig()** method return an instance of ServletConfig.

```
ServletContext sc=getServletConfig().getServletContext();
```

EDIT:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
  ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use getServletConfig() in the .java file but it complaints "The method getServletConfig() is undefined for ...". (Currently my .java class implements ServeletContextListener.) What else do I need to set up in order to use the getServletConfig()? Thanks.

Comment: Its in ServletContextEvent.getServletContext()