# Referencing a file within Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, path

When I reference to a DTD file in my code, I don't know how to reference to it within my project's folder. e.g : If my project's name is `Moo`, I'd want to refernce the DTD at `/Moo/WEB-INF/courses.dtd`.

```
TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = null;  

try { trans = transfac.newTransformer();   }
catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) { }

trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "/Moo/WEB-INF/courses.dtd");
```

But it doesn't find it. How can I reference it?

I was offered a solution using `getRealPath` problem is since my project will be read as a .war file this is not good. What should I do?

Comment: As a side note, never swallow exceptions. If you do so in examples, mark that approach for the sole purpose of brevity.

Comment: It was only written for the example, Will be changed in actual code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not include "Moo". For servlet root is one level up from WEB-INF.
Not sure that OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM wants relative path. Absolute path is:

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/courses.dtd");
```

Comment: Don't rely on `getRealPath()` will fail if your container does not expand the war file. Use always [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137565/how-do-i-access-file-in-web-inf-in-jsp/3137691#3137691).

Comment: but I don't want an InputStream I want a String, How do i get the string from this?

Comment: @nayish: If you need a String representation use `getRsource()`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String). Obtaining the file using the CLassloader requires you to put the DTD somewhere below `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: this is so old, but what is the best course for this? In my case, I have a key-file (like an SSH pem key) that I want to ship with my servlet app, and I need the full string representation of the path... and so I'm facing a similar issue you did

Answer (score 1):

So you're in the process of generating an XML document using XSLT. You want the document to be indented (`OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"`), and you want it to contain a DOCTYPE with a SYSTEM reference (`OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "..."`).

Now it's not likely that you want the real path of `$WebAppRoot/Moo/WEB-INF/courses.dtd` as the SYSTEM reference. Will it not rather be a URL, like `http://www.example.com/some/dir/courses.dtd`? And then the DTD should be available from that URL, of course. What resides in `WEB-INF` cannot be accessed via HTTP, at least not via the Servlet container.

If, on the other hand, you want to make the document and the DTD available only on the server that's building the document, then proceed as suggested by Nulldevice, with the caveats added in the comments.

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly do i need to do to link to it? I don;t mind moving the file around within the `Webcontent` folder and making it public either, so how exactly would i do this?

Comment: First, you should know whom you want to make the XML document available to, and how. If you want to make it publicly available via HTTP from your app server, then the DTD should be made available in the same way. If the doc is available from `http://bla.de/xy/doc.xml` and the DTD from `http://bla.de/xy/doc.dtd`, then you can use a relative URL, so just `doc.dtd`.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a [`URIResolver`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setURIResolver%28javax.xml.transform.URIResolver%29) to the `Transformer`.

Comment: Implement the interface and see what the Transformer will pass you at runtime. He will pass you the `SYSTEM` URL requesting you to resolve it. You then can return a source object containing the DTD.
Consider this as a proxy.